# gVim/Vim - how do I write vim buffer into a new (non vim) window?

Tags: vim

This might not be strictly a vim question, but here goes.
I have a proprietary IDE I'm working in, without any vim characteristics. I do, however, have keybindings.

My "diabolical plan" is to create a keybinding in the IDE (say Windows + V) to select all in the current buffer window in the IDE, open a gVim window, and dump the file into the window (perhaps setting filetype as well, but let's not get too fancy)

So the keybinding works to get it INTO a vim buffer - but how can I set up vim (either with a plugin or 3rd party tool) to grab the buffer on a :write and update the file in the IDE I launched it from?

Doable? Fool's errand?

Comment: Is the desired effect something like "It's all text" plugin for mozilla that is used for editing text in input fields in an external editor? The plugin opens a new file in gvim (or whatever), monitors changes to the file, and when it detects a change, it automagically pastes the new text into the input box. In this implementation, the magic is on the side of the invoking party - would this work for you?

Comment: That's 100% the approach I was thinking. I think I need a starting point.

Comment: You may edit the actual file in vim, save it then come back to your mysterious proprietary IDE which noticed the change and asks you if you want to load the modified file.

Comment: exactly. The part I've got to figure out is how to register the file name/path/whatever with the IDE, so it knows to monitor for changes. For now, I just created an autohotkey script bound to flush the changes into a new vim window, or flush back from vim into the IDE. It's fairly dangerous, however, in that there's no state remembered in terms of which buffer belongs where. But for the short term it will work until I can write hooks for the IDE. (if that's ever an option)

Comment: "It's just a quick fix to be replaced in the near future..." ;)

Answer (score 0):

If it's just about the IDE editor: write a [Visual Studio Addon](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mgold/AddIns11292005015631AM/AddIns.aspx).

If you want to make this transparently work for any application (like "It's all text!" that @xofon mentions)... World Domination!

As long as you can worry that this is a fool's errand, I already know you're not going to finish it. Geniuses go after their goals against all odds. Oh, and they reach them, of course. On-topic: I think you can manage this for selected standard controls only (and you'll run into walls especially as Windows is growing security awareness these days).

On WinNT/2000 and earlier it was as 'simple' as creating DLL injection, hooking window procs for the related controls and doing the grunt-work. Nowadays, I'm not so sure this is going to work without hitches. You'll run into process isolation issues, WOW isolation, clipboard sharing idiosyncrasies, Citrix/Terminal server sessions. So: I hope you are convinced you want to mount these kind of challenges. If so, I'm all for it. It would be great to have Vi support on windows surpassing that on any platform. `<dreams/>`

You might have a look at the docs for IME (Input-Method Editing). I'm afraid this won't let you achieve modal editing, really.